# How can I use Proxifier with Wine in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, wine

I used Proxifier in Windows, to bypass proxy firewalls.
In Ubuntu we have redsocks and proxychains which do the same job, but not Proxifier, I want to use proxifier in Ubuntu.
Can anyone tell me how can this be done, or whether it isn't possible to bypass proxy firewalls using windows emulators in Ubuntu.